# VS2013 Publish - FileSystem output as zip

Tags: .net, msdeploy, visual-studio-2013

Is there anyway to use VS2013 Publish profiles,     `<WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>`

and output a zip file of the finished publish?

I'm not looking for the Web Deploy Package, I'm looking for the File System mode, but zipping the published files

Answer (score 2):

You can get it to do this, and it's in the UI, although I can't actually manage to work out how I did it to do it again! The ***** help is all VS 2012 and generally is less than useful.

Looking inside the .pubxml file gives a clue though (I edited this to protect the guilty). As below, PackageAsSingleFile is what you need. You **can** make that work from the UI, which is how I got this, but now I can't find that bit of UI, but you could maybe put this XML in your file and try that...

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" ...>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>Package</WebPublishMethod>
...
    <ExcludeApp_Data>True</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <DesktopBuildPackageLocation>M:\OUTPUT.zip</DesktopBuildPackageLocation>
    <PackageAsSingleFile>true</PackageAsSingleFile>
    <DeployIisAppPath>Demonstration site</DeployIisAppPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: this didn't work for me. still copying all the files

Comment: You created this by selecting Package as deployment type in the Publish UI which gives you zip options, but this is **very different from File System** publish.  If you look at the directory structure created by Package, it is different than File System.  Package cannot simply be unzipped and overwrite the app, you have to use the deployment tool.